# PHP JSON value retrieval error

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a problem to retrieve **JSON** value from my **PHP** encoded **JSON** file

This is my **PHP** code:

```
$i = 0;
$qinfo = '';
$j=0;
$qry = "SELECT qid, q_title, q_question FROM questions WHERE qid = 1";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$data = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $qinfo[$i]['qid'] = $r['qid'];
    $qinfo[$i]['q_title'] = $r['q_title'];
    $qinfo[$i]['q_question'] = $r['q_question'];

    $qry2 = "SELECT aid, answer FROM answers WHERE qid=".$r['qid']." ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($qry2);

    while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $qinfo[$j]["Ans"]["aid"] = $r2['aid'];
        $qinfo[$j]["Ans"]["aid"] = $r2['answer'];

        $j++;
    }PHP
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($qinfo);
```

This is the output **JSON**:

```
[{
    "qid": "1",
    "q_title": "This is first question title",
    "q_question": "This is first question description",
    "Ans": {
        "aid": "26",
        "answer": "This is first answer"
    }
}, {
    "Ans": {
        "aid": "27",
        "answer": "This is second answer"
    }
}, {
    "Ans": {
        "aid": "28",
        "answer": "This is third"
    }
}]
```

1. Is this JSON format correct? simply explain: I am getting 1 question for answers.

Here this is the jQuery code I am trying to getting result.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,  
        dataType:"json",
        url: 'data.php',  
        success: function(data){
            $('.show_divis').each(function (index, value){
                var data_votes = '';

                data_votes += '<div style="color:#000">'+data[index].q_title+'</div>'; 
                data_votes += '<div style="color:#555">'+data[index].q_question+'</div>'; 

                $(this).html(data_votes).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(400);

                $('.show_divis2').each(function (index, value){
                    var data_votes2 = '';

                    data_votes2 += '<div style="color:#000">'+data[index].Ans.aid+'</div>'; 
                    data_votes2 += '<div style="color:#555">'+data[index].Ans.answer+'</div>'; 

                    $(this).html(data_votes2).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(400);
                });
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

It will show question title and description correctly. But only show 1 answer? according to my JSON file there are 3 answers. I want to show 3 answers under the question. May I have to change my JSON format?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The format you are using is definitely not convenient as the position in the top level array determines the question that the answer belongs to. it would be more logical to bundle all answers together in an array inside the question they belong to. Then you can use 2 nested loops in javascript just like you are doing already in php.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. HTML part only have 2 divs with that classes
<div class="show_divis"></div>
<div class="show_divis2"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is valid but format is incorrect as it should have all answers under one node like this:

```
[{
    "qid": "1",
    "q_title": "This is first question title",
    "q_question": "This is first question description",
    "Ans": [{
        "aid": "26",
        "answer": "This is first answer"
    },
    {
        "aid": "27",
        "answer": "This is second answer"
    },
    {
        "aid": "28",
        "answer": "This is third"
    }]
}]
```

To get above JSON format, please change your PHP code as following:

```
$i = 0;
$qinfo = array();
$qry = "SELECT qid, q_title, q_question FROM questions WHERE qid = 1";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $qinfo[$i]['qid'] = $r['qid'];
    $qinfo[$i]['q_title'] = $r['q_title'];
    $qinfo[$i]['q_question'] = $r['q_question'];

    $qry2 = "SELECT aid, answer FROM answers WHERE qid=".$r['qid']." ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($qry2);

    $j = 0;
    while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $qinfo[$i]["Ans"][$j]["aid"] = $r2['aid'];
        $qinfo[$i]["Ans"][$j]["answer"] = $r2['answer'];

        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($qinfo);
```

And the jQuery part:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,  
        dataType:"json",
        url: 'data.php',  
        success: function(data){
            var data_votes = '';

            $.each(data, function (index, questions){
                //console.log(questions);
                data_votes += '<div style="display: block; background-color: #eee; margin: 5px 0px; padding: 5px;">';
                data_votes += '<h2 style="padding: 5px; margin: 0px;">'+questions.q_title+'</h2>'; 
                data_votes += '<p style="padding: 5px;">'+questions.q_question+'</p>'; 

                $.each(questions.Ans, function (index, answers){
                    //console.log(answers);
                    data_votes += '<div style="color:#555; padding: 5px; margin: 2px 0px; background-color: #ccc;" id="answer_'+answers.aid+'">'+answers.answer+'</div>'; 
                });
                data_votes += '</div>';
            });
            // Add your reference to your desired html element instead of "BODY"
            $('body').append(data_votes);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, can you please little bit help with Jquery part too
I have already voted for this answer for you

Comment: What is the structure of `showdivis` and `showdivis2`? Can you these HTML in you question? I am able to understand why are you iterating these divs by `.each()` instead of iterating returned data from AJAX...

Comment: tell me the best way how to do it. I wan to show in 2 different divs, question under answers

Comment: can you please help me with the Jquery code? I am stuck